# delphi/firemonkey: how to implement a callback in the Activity?

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey

I need to implement this function :

```
  [JavaSignature('android/app/Activity')]
  JActivity = interface(JContextThemeWrapper)
    ...  
    procedure onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Integer; permissions: TJavaObjectArray<JString>; grantResults: TJavaArray<Integer>); cdecl;
    ....
```

but how to do this ? this function is only to receive event, so i must override it, but i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Your question subject is misleading. Implementing event functions in Android is done by taking a Delphi version of the published listener interface and implementing in a Delphi class that inherits from `TJavaLocal` in the Androidapi.JNIBridge unit.
You are asking how to implement a callback in the `Activity` that underlies your entire Delphi application.

Comment: thanks blong, you are right, i just updated the question to be more accurate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement a callback in the [`Activity`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that underlies your FireMonkey application you have to write some Java code to subclass FireMonkey's own native activity subclass.

This is rather tedious and fraught with issues, and requires various command-line "monkey-business" but I've written the process up for a different callback, [`onNewIntent`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) in [my Delphi XE7 article on supporting NFC tags](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE7NFC/NFC.htm#ReceivingIntents) (Delphi 10 Seattle made this job feasible without Java activity subclassing). I also wrote the process up for Delphi XE5 for the [`onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) callback in [the first version of my article on launching Android activities](http://blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE5AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#HandlingResult) (Delphi XE6 made this job possible without Java activity subclassing).

Be sure to update your Android manifest template file as done with the samples that accompany those articles to refer to the new custom activity subclass, as in:

```
<activity android:name="com.blong.test.NativeActivitySubclass"
          ...
```

Good luck with that. It's rather messy and makes debugging very difficult.

Comment: Thanks blong, i already read all your blog and watch your seminar :) thanks to this i already made my own classes.dex. I understand how to subclass any object like textview for example, but i don't understand how to subclass the FMXNativeActivity because it's will be delphi who will create it not me, so it's will never be created with my own subclass (or i miss something). This part i didn't quite well understand in your blog, how to start the main activity with my own subclass instead of default FMXNativeActivity (because else my java code will be useless i guess)

Comment: OK, if you're already familiar with the material and the processes then you have all the information you require. Those two articles cover all the required steps (for the product versions in question) and have accompanying samples showing the results functioning well.
If there is something unclear in there you'll need to be more specific in the questions you ask or the problems you report.

Comment: "i don't understand how to subclass the FMXNativeActivity because it's will be delphi who will create it not me" -> Oh, actually I see one things not stressed in the articles is the change required to the Android manifest file to have the activity subclass be created on aplication startup. I have updated my answer accordingly. If you find this now answers the issue, please do the appropriate upvoting of useful comments and marking of appropriate answers (here and on other recent questions).

Comment: Thanks blong! it's work perfectly now !! I also add a feature request to emb ( https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15986 ) because i think it's could be better in futur if all of this is handled directly by delphi

Comment: @blong: "Delphi 10 Seattle made this job feasible without Java activity subclassing" - are you referring to the NFC functions specifically, or to other activity subclassing as well?

Comment: @DaveNottage, nothing NFC-specific, no. I'm referring to picking up intents in Delphi from the underlying activity's `onNewIntent` method, which Seattle adds functionality to surface to Delphi code without messy sleeve-rolling required. The NFC article shows an example of doing this, but then again so does [this Seattle example](https://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Seattle/Object%20Pascal/Mobile%20Snippets/AndroidIntents/) - look at the HTML ReadMe file. This is similar to the XE6 support for `onActivityResult` (also surfaced into the messaging framework).

Comment: "Good luck with that. It's rather messy and makes debugging very difficult." When I reported this: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16145, it was actually impossible, at least via the Delphi debugger.